# Nodejs+Mongoose : find and update

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to `search` for a `document` in my `mongo database` then using the `found document data` to *search another document and then update both*. First document is to be saved after the second document is found.

But with my code the first document saves but doesnot saves updated data

**My code :**

```
 var posts = {};
 Posts.findOne({'url': req.body.url}, function(err, data){
            posts = data;
            //console.log(data);
            Comments.findOne({'bucket': posts.bucket}, function(err, data){
                var comment= data;
                if(data.count>10){
                   posts.bucket = posts.bucket +1;
                   comment.bucket = comment.bucket +1;
                }
                comment.save(function(err, data){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                });
            });
            posts.save(function(err, data){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                res.json(data);
            });
        });
```

I observed that whatever changes is done in `posts` variable in  `Comments.findOne({...})` it remains local to it and doesnot effect outer `posts` varible, but it is just declared once. so how can i do this. Is something wrong in code? How do I do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First document is to be saved after the second document is found.

In your code you're saving the `comment` and the `post` in a parallel manner, you need to save the post after saving the `document` :

```
var posts = {};
 Posts.findOne({
     'url': req.body.url
 }, function(err, data) {
     posts = data;
     //console.log(data);
     Comments.findOne({
         'bucket': posts.bucket
     }, function(err, data) {
         var comment = data;
         if (data.count > 10) {
             posts.bucket = posts.bucket + 1;
             comment.bucket = comment.bucket + 1;
         }
         comment.save(function(err, data) {
             if (err)
                 throw err;

             posts.save(function(err, data) {
                 if (err)
                     throw err;
                 res.json(data);
             });
         });
     });

 });
```

Another important remark: you're creating a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) which leads to unknown behavior later. Please use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [promises](https://github.com/then/promise) instead of nesting callbacks.